# Random Access Stream with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, stream, random-access

I tried to find out if there exists a stream API for random access streams in JavaScript.

I was checking the [Streams-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) and from my understanding there is no classic `read(offset, length)`.

From what I see is that I can `fetch` a resource from the web and `response.body` exposes the body as `ReadableStream`. Depending on the browser I use I can use the `ReadableStream()` constructor and pass a custom implementation for `start` and `pull`. Would it be possible to create a random access stream by properly implementing `start` and `pull`?

Comment: You have to buffer all the data.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not aware of a stream implementation that does random access. As far as I'm aware, streams are designed to be consumable only once, so you can't really "rewind" to a previous position and "fast forwarding" to some data is usually reading and discard items until you get to the one of interest. Unless you buffer the data, in which case you'd be able to "go back" by looking at what's in the buffer but I'm not sure if there is already an implementation of that.

Comment: But how do for example Netflix and Youtube deal with this? I cannot imagine if I jump to a certain forward position of my 2 hour video that the whole video will be streamed up to that point? Do they have a back end that prepares a new stream from the desired starting location?

Comment: Well, YouTube only buffers a small amount of the video. You can move freely within the buffer but if you jump to, say, 30 minutes ahead in a video you'd need to wait to get the data from the server for it. So it seems it's the backend doing that. Not sure about Netflix but I suspect they are doing something similar. Also, at least some time back, Netflix was using a Silverlight player, so it was hardly bound by JS streams then. I don't even know if they were available then. Not sure about it nowadays - haven't used it.